# Limit over one variable for two variable function

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, power-series

For function $f(x,y)$ I want to find out $\displaystyle \lim_{y \to +0} f(x,y) $. By substituting $y=0$, I get $\displaystyle f(x,0) = \frac{0}{0}$. Is it valid to use L'Hospital's rule.
In my case I have arrived at $f(x,y)$ as a power series expression derived from a complicated function involving Bessel function. Problem is after applying L'Hospital's rule I am getting required expression with all the required terms involving log functions etc but with one extra constant term. Final expression is very unintuitive from original function.
Additional point is $f(x,y)$ is monotonically increasing of $x$ for all values of $y$. Also for non-zero values of $y$, $f(x,y)$ is bounded function of $x$. Slope of $f(x,y)$ with respect to $x$ is steeper for low values of $y$. $f(0,y) = 0$ for all positive values of $y$ according to original expression. I am not able to get any discrepancy in my derivation. Derivation is based on first principles without application any advanced theorems etc.

Comment: Provide more information about your function.

Comment: @ravi What is the function $f(x,y)$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course, by definition, we can consider $x$ as a constant and evaluate the limit for

$$\lim_{y\to 0} g(y)=\lim_{(x,y)\to (x,0)}f(x,y)$$

and since we obtain an indeterminate form we can use l'Hospital or other methods depending on the nature of the specific function $g(y)$.